# sum(Amount} only totals positive numbers in my table. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sum

I have a table that contains hours for jobs technicians perform.  The majority of the entries are positive but occasionally there is a credit to the customer that show as negative hours.  My query includes sum(Amount) but only sums the positive numbers.  It should sum 2 + 2 - 4 as 0, but it's giving me a total of 4.

Example of table

```
job no.    Amount
  j211      2
  j211      2
  j211     -4

select job no. sum(Amount)
from service.jobs
where job no. = 'j211'
group by job no.
```

This returns a total Amount for j211 of 4, not 0.

Comment: Please setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6) that demonstrates your issues.

Comment: Because what you have described here [does work as you want](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb8d8/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this one. try this one. and compare your table with this one.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[service](
[jobno] [varchar](5) NULL,
[amount] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Insert into service(jobno,amount) 
Select 'j211',2 UNION ALL
Select 'j211',2 UNION ALL
Select 'j211',-4

select sum(Amount)
from service
where jobno = 'j211'
group by jobno
```